# How to tell my go build to look in the vendor folder for the godep libraries?

Tags: go, godeps

I have a simple Dockerfile that I am trying to build and run my Go REST API server.

My Dockerfile so far is:

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

When I run docker-compose up I get this error:

```
main.go:12:2: cannot find package "github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache" in any of:
```

I am using godeps and my vendor folder has all the libraries vendored, why isn't the build working in this case?

Do I have to tell it to look in the vendor folder?

Comment: @MartinTournoij I just assume that the issue is that I have to give some sort of flag to look in the vendor/ folder for deps.

Comment: No, you don't. The error output should actually says it's looking in the vendor directory (the part that you omitted).

Answer (score 1):

The `vendor` directory does not function as expected if your source code lies outside of `GOPATH` (see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14566). In the current `golang:latest` Docker image, `GOPATH` is set to `/go` so the simplest solution would be to copy your code into a subdirectory of `/go/src` and build from there.